# In python, how to keep id of list unchanged when we changed list contents

Tags: python-2.7

I want remove list `b` from list `a` without changing id of list `a` I tried below method:

```
for i in b:
    a.remove(i)
```

Is there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 3]

for i in b:
    try:
        a.remove(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print a
```

Alternatively:

```
a = [i for i in a if i not in b]
print a
```